# Error while creating new project on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have installed Visual Studio 2010 successfully. Whenever I try to create a new project from Visual Studio I am getting error. Please check this screenshot.
[image]

Comment: My first guess would be that Visual Studio doesn't have the necessary rights to create the project.

Comment: So what can I do to make my visual studio to work properly.

Comment: Were you trying to create a Visual Basic application?  Have you _ever_ been able to create a new project?  You can try running Visual Studio in administrator mode (right click the icon to do this).